movie about a house that lives off of people
I've been searching everywhere for this with no luck. 
The movie starts off with a paranormal investigative team going to this house with a big black gate to stay the night and investigate the house. The house has a keeper he stays there and takes care of the house. They get killed off one by one I remember one scene where a guy who disappeared and thought to be killed was found in the wall of the house where someone accidentally made a hole. No one can leave the house or surrounding yard or they die. They tried calling the police and the police were impaled by the fence and their bodies disappeared. Also I remember they eventually went into a shed and found a well where the house keeper was putting the bodies to feed to the house.  At the end one of the guys turns into the next house keeper and welcomes a couple for a nights stay. That's pretty much what I remember I wish I had more information if anyone could help that'd be greatly appreciated thank you.

You probably mean House of Bones with Charisma Carpenter from 2010 where a house kills a crew of TV ghost hunters one by one. They find out the bodies are fed to a well, and in the end one of them becomes the house's new caretaker. Here's a trailer.
